# VS2010, VSpackage, adding command for certain filetypes in the context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm developing a vspackage for executing *.bat files in my vs2010 solutions.

Therefore I need a button when I right click my files to get a context-menu in solution explorer.

I would like the button only to be visible when right clicking *.bat files. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this quite easily. First, you need to create menu item in solution explorer context menu. You can learn how to add menu items in general on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165468(v=vs.90).aspx).
To be more exact, you need set your menu group's parent to:
<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE"/>
Both guid and id are predefined in Visual studio, the latter means that the menu item will be displayed whenever user clicks on standard project item. However, you need it only to appear when the name of the file ends with ".bat". This can be achived in BeforeQueryStatus method - see MSDN link above. To find out selected nodes in solution explorer, use 
(UIHierarchy)ideObject.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Object

which has SelectedItems property.